# Symfony2 allow anonymous for certain routes with certain methods

Tags: php, api, rest, symfony

I am developing a backend service for my own project with Symfony2. What i would like to do is simple user registration. Whenever a user needs to be created there will be a POST call to

```
/v1.0/users (with POST method)
```

I would like to create a new user. For all of the other url should be authenticated except this one. So I created UserProvider and UserAuthenticator as described in here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html

I created a secured area and it works fine, but i want to disable this firewal for the url above with post method. I couldnt figure it out how. Here is my security.yml file

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    api_user_secured_area:
        pattern: ^/v1.0/users
        stateless: true
        simple_preauth:
            authenticator: user_token_authenticator
        provider: user_token_provider

    access_control:
    ...
        user_register:
            path: /v1.0/users
            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY ?? FOR POST ONLY ??
```

PS: I dont want to use annotation for security (like @Security in the controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access control can be filtered to a given METHOD using the Methods property, please see here for more filters/options regarding access control:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html

Here is the option integrated into your code:

```
access_control:
    user_register:
        path: /v1.0/users
        methods: [ POST ]
        roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
```

Comment: I have one other issue now. I made this change but it still doesnt let me do it.